# Export mutli-pdf directly

Tags: beamer, xetex

I have a big latex beamer project that includes multi-chapters. I need to export each chapter in a separate pdf file.

Do we have any way to export each include file in a separate PDF?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% To Pass graphics paths
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/chapter-01/}}
\input{preamble/preamble.tex}
\input{./front_page.tex}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

    %---------------------------------------------------------
    %The next statement creates the title page.
    \frame{\titlepage}

    %---------------------------------------------------------
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \include{Ch01}
    \include{Ch02}
    \include{Ch03}
    \include{Ch04}
    \include{Ch04}
    \include{Ch05}
    \include{Ch06}
    \include{Ch07}
    \include{Ch08}
    \include{Ch09}
    \include{Ch10}
    \include{Appendix}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}


%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

Comment: In short, no: TeX isn't designed to produce multiple output files.

Comment: Compile your document with all the chapters then make one document by chapter using `pdfpages` to extract each chapter (and using `pax` to keep all links).

Comment: Did the above comments help solve your question ?

Comment: @BambOo It can solve the problem in general, but it didn't answer my question. But it seems we can't do this with Latex. I wrote a custom shell script for this answer. I will try to clean it up and upload it. As my main idea was to search for an automated tex solution but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I do not think that a TeX-only solution is possible either. Feel free to answer your own question with the script you mention, I am sure it may be of help for other users !